# Change the block start string in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates, latex

I'm creating a web based application in Django. The app will generate multi-page pdf reports with Latex. Currently I'm generating the tex files using Jinja2. Since my web app is using the Django template engine, I thought I might as well use it to generate the tex file that will be sent to pdflatex. In Jinja2 I changed the block_start_string and block_end_string from {% and %} to {@ and @} respectively. I did this so that it plays nicely with Latex.

My question is, can I change block_start_string to {@ in Django, but only for the part of my code that needs to generate the tex files? My html templates should still use {% and %}. Jinja2 has a concept of environments, not sure if Django also has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does not currently support changing the block start or end strings, however Django does support using Jinja2 as a template backend. This way, you can use your existing templates.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/